# IntelliJ Ultimate Editor Syntax Highlighting for Jest

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, syntax-highlighting

I am writing javascript unit tests using Jest in IntelliJ Ultimate.

Everything works great, and I can even run the tests right in the editor. There's just one thing I'd like to fix: the jest functions are not syntax-highlighted and the editor underlines them to show them as errors because it can't find definitions for `describe()`, `beforeEach()`, `it()`, etc.  Not a show stopper at all, but it is annoying to look at.

How do I get the editor to recognize and highlight the jest functions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your IntelliJ settings.  Open Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries.  Click on the "Download..." button and search for "jest".  Select it and click "Download and Install".
[image]

Once it's installed, your editor should now recognize and use syntax highlighting on jest functions.
[image]

Note: this is the source for my answer, to give credit to where it's due:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000125310-Angular-TypeScript-Jest-Syntax-Highlighting